# C++ Overloading the function operator and inheritance, can't use it properly within a subclass function

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I am a student and this is my first semester with c++, so I apologise in advance for any sloppy code.
I need help with operation overloading, particularly the function operator () and inheritance. I have trolled the net for info to no avail.
What I am trying to do; I have overloaded the function operation () in class RandomInt and I am now trying to access that from an inherited class BankAcct, specifically I am trying to access it from within a public function.
I removed all comments to make the code shorter. scroll down to bankacct.cpp to see the code that needs correcting.
I have a working randomInt.cpp and randomInt.h file

randomInt.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef RANDOMINT_H
#define RANDOMINT_H

class RandomInt {
    public:

        RandomInt();

        RandomInt(int ia, int ib);

        int get_random_int();

        int operator()();

        int operator()(int num_b);

        int operator()(int num_a, int num_b);

    private: 
        int a , b, randomInt;
};
#endif
```

and randomInt.cpp

```
#include "randomInt.h"

using namespace std;

RandomInt::RandomInt(){
    a = 1000; 
    b = 9999;
    randomInt = 0;
}

RandomInt::RandomInt(int ia, int ib){
    a = ia; 
    b = ib;
    randomInt = 0;
}

int RandomInt::get_random_int(){
    return randomInt;
}

int RandomInt::operator()(){
    return randomInt = a + rand() % (b - a + 1);
}

int RandomInt::operator()(int num_b){
    return randomInt = a + rand() % (num_b - a + 1);
}

int RandomInt::operator()(int num_a, int num_b){
    return randomInt = num_a + rand() % (num_b - num_a + 1);
}
```

Now I have implemented these just fine on there own.

Now the following is compiling and is working the way I want it to but I'm sure there is a better way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "randomInt.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef BANKACCT_H
#define BANKACCT_H

class BankAcct : public RandomInt { 
    public:

        BankAcct();

        string get_pinCode();        

        string get_BSB();

        string int_to_string(int integer); 

    private: 
        string BSB;
        string pinCode;
        void set_pinCode();
};
#endif
```

and the bankacct.cpp file

```
#include "bankacct.h"
#include "randomInt.h"

using namespace std;

BankAcct::BankAcct(){
    BSB = "324-001";
}

string BankAcct::get_pinCode(){
    set_pinCode();
    return pinCode;
}

string BankAcct::get_BSB(){
    return BSB;
}

string BankAcct::int_to_string(int integer) {
    stringstream out;
    out << integer;  
    return out.str();
}

void BankAcct::set_pinCode(){
    // THIS IS WHERE I BELIEVE THE ISSUE IS.
    RandomInt R;
    int code = R();
    pinCode = int_to_string(code); 
}
```

I have initialised a class object to get it to work where as in my past assignments where I use inheritance I could simply call an inherited class function. can some one help me please? or provide the correct syntax.

I am then compiling as follows to check.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "bankacct.h"
#include "randomInt.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
srand(time(0));
BankAcct newAcct;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << newAcct.get_pinCode() << endl;
        cout << newAcct.get_BSB() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

remember it is working as intended but I don't see why I should have to make a class object like I did.

Any help would be great please.

Comment: Why do you use inheritance in the first place ? Don't need it here, a BankAccount is NOT a randomInt, is it ? Just drop the inheritance.

Comment: Kiroxas's point aside, what did you try?  Working through it... the current object is `(*this)`, and you want to use it like a function - that should suggest something ;-P.

Comment: Unrelated: you're going to have issues with things like `a + rand()` if RAND_MAX on your platform is synonymous with `INT_MAX`. You should probably be aware of that overflow condition.

Comment: Search for CRTP and static polymorphism. Thats the easiest and most efficient way to acieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the unnecessary inheritance of `RandomInt` for `BankAcct`, there is nothing wrong with using classes. You can remove the inheritance by simply using `class BankAcct {`.

Your code works fine, and you have declared the class `RandomInt` to easily set up the randomiser variables.

Regarding inheritance, you say you have used the function names before to access the functions of the base class. Within the functions of the inherited class you can only do that for functions and not operators, as you cannot simply call `int code = ();` because that does not make any sense.

Inheritance is mostly useful when an inherited class extends on a base class. I would like suggest [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm) to indicate the advantage of inheritance. In your example, `BankAcct` simply uses a `RandomInt` instead of being an extension to `RandomInt` and therefore inheritance is not needed.

Comment: Unrelated: I hope you also notice that every time you call `get_pinCode()`, it creates a new pincode. You probably want to move `set_pinCode()` to the constructor.

Comment: Yeah I need a new pin code each  time. This is half of the assignment. The idea is to generate a new random pin code for each bank account. The bank account number will be generated using another class I have made that provides a sequential number each time.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the comments. You have all got me thinking maybe I can achieve what I want by getting bankUSQ_app to use RandomInt object and the Serial object(this I have not supplied code for above) to create the serial and random numbers(pin code). Then BankAcct objects will assign those numbers to their data members. Thanks again for your replies, sometimes that's what's needed to get you to think of other approaches